# Abort trap: 6 with loop in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, unique

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {

            if (strcmp(aircraft_array[j], aircraft_array[i])==0) {

                for (int k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    strcpy(aircraft_array[k],aircraft_array[k+1]);
                }
                size--;
            } else
                j++;
        }
    }
```

Hello guys

I have copied this code from `http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/to-delete-duplicate-elements-in-array.html`. However the code is giving me the error **Abort code 6**. I am not entirely sure what that means.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I tested the code by putting print statements and the code breaks right here.

Comment: `aircraft_array[k+1]` is out of bounds, isn't it?

Comment: What is `aircraft_array` and please check its bounds?

Comment: I cant say for sure as you didnt post some important code however if I were to guess I would say you are probably writing to memory that your program does not own. probably to do with the strpcpy

Comment: @JackVanier How should  I approach removing duplicate strings from *aircraft_array[10000] ?

Comment: Trap, means you entered the debugger, probably because you overstepped a buffer.

Comment: @nullpointer it is an array that is storing strings;  char *aircraft_array[10000]

Comment: @Newbie  There are many bad codes in the internet.:) My congratulations. You found one more.:)

Comment: @Newbie  If it is an array of string literals then you may not modify them.

Comment: @Newbie  Also could you say why should we discuss this bad code that you found in the internet?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh I am not saying we need to discuss bad code. I am new to C and just wanted some help from better people.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And I do not think the code is bad because the original code works fine integers. It breaks when adapting to string for some reason I cant put my finger on

Comment: @Newbie Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, learning through this format is not ideal (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/is-stack-overflow-an-effective-platform-for-studying-programming). I would recommend Bruce Eckel's Thinking in C++ (http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html).

Comment: @Newbie Who are "better people"? :) Nevertheless it is a bad code. Even if it will be written correctly it is inefficient.

Comment: @KCWong Yes and I asked a question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You guys. You are proficient at what you do.

Comment: @Newbie In writing comments?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow idk dude. My guess would be drinking vodka.

Comment: "the original code works fine integers". It doesn't. You have tested it and didn't find an error. It doesn't mean there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
strcpy(aircraft_array[k],aircraft_array[k+1]);
                                       ^^^^^
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when `k` is equal to `size-1`.

This increment

```
        } else
            j++;
            ^^^^
```

does not make sense because the variable also is incremented in the loop statement

```
 for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                               ^^^^
```

that is it is incremented twice. Moreover when a subarray was copied the variable `j` shall not be incremented.

And it is inefficient to copy a whole subarray when a duplicate is found.

The function can look differently depending on whether it deals with a two dimensional character array or an array of pointers to strings.

In case when there is a two-dimensional array the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t remove_duplicates( size_t m, size_t n, char s[static const m][n] )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( size_t j = 0; j < m; j++ )
    {
        size_t k = 0;
        while ( k != i && strcmp( s[k], s[j] ) != 0 ) k++;

        if ( k == i )
        {
            if ( i != j ) strcpy( s[i], s[j] );
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[][2] = { "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A" };
    size_t N = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    size_t n = remove_duplicates( N, 2, s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A B A C D A 
A B C D
```

If there is an array of pointers then the function can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t remove_duplicates( char * s[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        size_t k = 0;
        while ( k != i && strcmp( s[k], s[j] ) != 0 ) k++;

        if ( k == i )
        {
            if ( i != j ) s[i] = s[j];
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * s[] = { "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A" };
    size_t N = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    size_t n = remove_duplicates( s, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is the same as shown above

```
A B A C D A 
A B C D
```